How to stop C# console app from closing immediately and run function before?
My app requires to run function to dispose all resources and send packet about closing connection and I need to prevent insta death of my app and run some code before closing by pressing CTRL+C or Cross
I tried subscribing to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit but sometimes function seems to dont run or run partially

how about a simple Console.ReadLine() ?
This will wait for the next keyboard input before terminate your console app

Have you looked into multithreading? Kind of basic idea but you could wrap the main logic in Thread mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainFunction)); That way you could interrupt the main thread and run some logic to free everything and send a packet on close. (Not the best implementation, but probably something that won't be in the 'This question already has answers here' part
